# How to select table row by cell content using jquery

Tags: jquery

Let's suppose I have the following table

```
<table id='tID'>
<tr><td>host1</td><td>user1</td><td>str1</td></tr>
<tr><td>host2</td><td>user1</td><td>str2</td></tr>
<tr><td>host2</td><td>user2</td><td>str3</td></tr>
<tr><td>host2</td><td>user1</td><td>str4</td></tr>
</table>
```

I use the following command to select the row by one cell

```
$("table#tID tr:contains('user1')");
```

I need to select for example those rows that contain user1 && host2 using jquery. Is it possible?

Comment: So the cell HAS to contain either user1 or host2, or must contain both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$("table#tID tr:contains('user1'):contains('host2')");
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/EXRv6/)</kbd>

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

---

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/EXRv6/1)</kbd> by [oGeez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612146/ogeez)

```
$("table#tID tr").filter(function () {
    $cells = $(this).children('td');
    return ($cells.eq(0).text() === 'host2' && $cells.eq(1).text() === 'user1')
}).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: What about when/if it's `user11, user12`, etc?